# Why does my SKLabelNode go off the page if the score increases

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, position, sklabelnode

So I have an SKLabelNode which displays the users high score, when the users highs score is for example 5 the labels position isn't in the same position to where it would be if the score was for example 35, or 100 makes the label go off screen, please can someone help with this issue, is there a way to make the label stay in the same position if the high score changes? do I need to put constraints on the label? BTW this is in sprite kitand using swift[image: Highscore label is off the screen]

[image: Highscore label isn't the same position as the other picture]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use [SKLabelNodeHorizontalAlignmentMode.Left](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKLabelNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKLabelNode/horizontalAlignmentMode) here, like this:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    var label = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "ArialMT")

    var score: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            label.text = "Score: \(score)"
        }
    }

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {


        label.fontSize = 24
        label.text = "Score: \(score)"

        //Place the label in upper left corner of the screen
        label.position = CGPoint(x: 50, y: CGRectGetMaxY(frame)-50)

        //Add this
        label.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode.Left

        addChild(label)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        score+=5
    }
}
```

The result:

[image: alignment mode left]

Comment: thanks for response, however using your position makes the label completely go off the view, and adding the horizontalAlignmentMode.Left only leaves the end on the label on the view. I've tried using .Right  but that sets the label off the view aswell, To make it clear, this is my Highscore label code -

Comment: the position used to be - .position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2 + 60, y: self.frame.height / 2 + 335)

Comment: Sure, you have to reposition your label accordingly. Just move the label a bit to the right.

Comment: so your position sets the position to be top left, how come the label is off the view then?

Comment: @AndrewHarris No problem, glad to hear it works! If this answer helped you with to solve the issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Hi @Whirlwind, how can I get CGRectGetMaxY ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try changing the node's anchorPoint from (0.5, 0.5), which is the default, to (0, 0). This means that the node will now be "anchored" to the top left corner instead of the middle.

EDIT:
(0, 0) in SpriteKit is BOTTOM LEFT. Use (0, 1) instead for TOP LEFT!

Comment: thanks for the quick response! I'm quite new to SKLabelNodes, how would I add this anchorPoint to the label?

Comment: `scoreLabel.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 1)`

Comment: the only problem is that SKLabelNode has no member anchorPoint

Comment: Whoops - sorry about that! You're right, and the other answer is correct :)